# how to split one row into 2 lines, interactive grid oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5, interactive-grid

There are a lot of columns to edit in this interactive grid, i want to split the row into 2 lines

interactive grid
[image]

like this

[image]

i do not know if possible or not

is there a way to do it?

I did a lot of research, but I couldn't do anything because I couldn't find a working example.

Comment: Pretty sure that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> ... lot of columns to **edit**

If your intention is to edit values, then - as far as I can tell - you can't do that. At least, not with built-in Apex capabilities.

On the other hand, if you wanted to **display** values in two rows, then you could use a query that includes `<br>` tag:

```
select empno,
ename ||'<br>'|| job namjob,
sal
from emp
```

Edit `namjob` column's properties and turn its "Escape special characters" property OFF. Result is then

[image]

That works on Apex ver. **20**. Though, why bother with Interactive Grid if you can do that in Interactive or Classic Report ...

---

However, on Apex ver. **23** (that currently runs on apex.oracle.com), that "trick" won't work any more because there's no "Escape special characters" property any more. It means that previous code results in

[image]

If you thought that CRLF fixes it, nope:

```
select empno,
ename ||chr(10)||chr(13)|| job namjob,
sal
from emp
```

In SQL*Plus result looks like this (`job` *is* in another row):

```
     EMPNO NAMJOB                       SAL
---------- --------------------- ----------
      7369 SMITH                        840
            CLERK
```

but in Apex everything is in the same line:

[image]

---

The bottom line is: I doubt you can do what you wanted.